# Cross referencing in knime

Tags: java, oracle, knime

I'm using Knime and I need to be able to cross reference a value within a csv file against a value I get from an Oracle DB.

Specifically, I need to match a ZIP code I get from the DB to a CSV file I have that contains zip codes and their corresponding counties.

I'm not really sure how to approach it. I've tried Joins and Cross joins but the data ends up looking garbled and I'm unable to make any sense of it. Worst case scenario I end up manually looking things up.

Comment: It's pretty hard to suggest a solution if the only problem description we have is *the data ends up looking garbled*. Can you show us an actual example of what you're doing now, what result you get and what you wanted to get?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding only one column (county in this example) I prefer [Cell Replacer](https://kni.me/n/71a_wzUQb9FDO9iU) node with option to Append column. Easier to configure and faster than [Joiner](https://kni.me/n/ZgYyOm1P9VJVBE9e) node.